# How can I use PriorityBlockingQueue with ListeningExecutorService?

Tags: guava

Since Guava's ListeningExecutorService is implemented by wrapping an existing ExecutorService, it 'decorates' the task by intercepting the execute() method. That means that if I want to use a custom PriorityQueue on the underlying ExecutorService, my comparator "sees" the decorated task as a ListenableFutureTask object instead of the original.

Is there a way to get a hold of the task that it wraps? So that the queue's comparator can use the tasks weight to determine ordering?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you're concerned with `submit()` rather than `execute()`? (See the bottom of my response.)

With a `ListeningExecutorService` from `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator` (the kind of wrapper you refer to), you're out of luck. `listeningDecorator`, like most `ExecutorService` implementations, wraps any input to `submit` in a `FutureTask`. The normal solution to this problem is to implement `AbstractExecutorService` and override `newTaskFor` to return a custom object. That should work here, too. You'll basically be reimplementing `listeningDecorator`, which is a fairly trivial wrapper around `AbstractListeningExecutorService`, which is itself a fairly trivial wrapper around `AbstractExecutorService`.

There are two couple complications. (OK, there might be more. I admit that I haven't tested the approach I'm suggesting.)

1. `AbstractListeningExecutorService` doesn't allow you to override `newTaskFor`. (Why? I can explain if you'd like to [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/entry).) As a result, you'll have to *extend `AbstractExecutorService` directly*, largely duplicating the (short) `AbstractListeningExecutorService` implementation.
2. `newTaskFor` has to return a `ListenableFuture` that's also `Comparable`. The obvious choice for a `ListenableFuture` is `ListenableFutureTask`, but that class is `final`, so you can't make instances `Comparable`. The solution is to create a `ListenableFutureTask` and *wrap it in a `SimpleForwardingListenableFuture`* that implements `Comparable`.

---

Why do I assume you're dealing with `submit()` rather than `execute()`?

`listeningDecorator(...).execute()` doesn't wrap the input task, as shown by this test I just wrote:

```
public void testListeningDecorator_noWrapExecuteTask() {
  ExecutorService delegate = mock(ExecutorService.class);
  ListeningExecutorService service = listeningDecorator(delegate);
  Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {}
  };
  service.execute(task);
  verify(delegate).execute(task);
}
```